# Select with variable Nodejs Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have this request:

```
var cartes = "SELECT type_carte, classe, date_validite, gare_depart, gare_arrivee, id_client WHERE id_client='" +clcour+ "'";
connection.query(cartes, function(error, lescartes) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Cartes chargés');
        cartescl = lescartes;
    }
});
```

but I got a `MYSQL SYNTAX ERROR: use near 'WHERE id_client='5' ' at line 1`

Any help on why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the `FROM table` in the query.

```
SELECT type_carte, classe, date_validite, gare_depart, gare_arrivee, id_client
FROM your_table
WHERE id_client = ?;
```

Also consider using prepared statements to mitigate injections.
Another issue you might have. `WHERE id_client = '5'`. I advice you to have IDs as numeric values `UNSIGNED INT` might be a good start. In that case you should `WHERE id_client = 5` (no '). But best is to use prepared statements. Then you don't have to worry at all.